# cannot see textures from inside a sphere opengl-es

Tags: opengl-es

I am learning opengl es 2, and I have a sphere with a texture. I have no problems to see it from outside, but if i put the camera inside, all I see is dark. I tried to solve this with:

GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);

But I still see a black screen. It is due to light? what can I do to see the texture from inside the sphere?

These are the shaders:

```
final String vertexShader =
        "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      \n"     // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.

                + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.
                + "varying vec2 vTexCoord;        \n"
                + "attribute vec2 vTexCoord0;     \n"
                + "void main()                    \n"     // The entry point for our vertex shader.
                + "{                              \n"
                + "   gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix   \n"     // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
                + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in
                + "   vTexCoord = vTexCoord0;     \n"
                + "}                              \n";    // normalized screen coordinates.


final String fragmentShader =
        "precision mediump float;                          \n"
                + "varying vec2 vTexCoord;                           \n"
                + "uniform sampler2D sTexture;                       \n"
                + "void main()                                       \n"
                + "{                                                 \n"
                + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( sTexture, vTexCoord );\n"
                + "}
```

Comment: Depends on how your shader is written

Comment: I have posted the shaders.

Comment: Then it's not lights since the shaders don't have any light calculation in them

Comment: After 3 years, I was going to test the Project again, had to change the target SDK version, and only with that change, I see the textures from inside. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

```
GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK);
```

tells it to cull (not show) both front and back-facing tris. You shouldn't see anything from either inside or outside with that setting. Try "NONE" instead.

Comment: I tried GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_NONE); and still don't see nothing

Comment: OK. Then it might perhaps be due to near clipping? What's the size of the sphere and what is the near clipping range set to in your projection matrix?

Answer (score 0):

GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK); means you want it to cull (i.e. not render) both the front AND back. It's hard to imagine a situation where anyone would ever want to do that.

To turn off culling in C, you'd need to do

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

I presume for your Java binding the command looks like

```
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
```